# appendChild doesn't work when I'm trying to move span

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a div in one place and I want to move it to another 2 places. I have id's for two parent tags and my spanEN to move. When I appendChild it only works for parentHeader.appendChild(spanEN );

```
        var parentNav = document.getElementById('js-liveChatParentNav');
        var parentHeader = document.getElementById('js-liveChatParentHeader');

        var spanEN = document.getElementById("js-chat-sourceEN").childNodes[1];

        parentNav.appendChild(spanEN );
        parentHeader.appendChild(spanEN );
```

in console I see this: one appendChild works and the other one dosen't.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `appendChild` to append an element that's already in the DOM, it's **moved**, not cloned. If you want to clone it, you can, via `cloneNode`:

```
parentNav.appendChild(spanEN);
parentHeader.appendChild(spanEN.cloneNode(true));
// ----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `true` means "clone this node *and* its descendants."